# How do I make my richTextBox search case-insensitive?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, find

I am making a word processor. The word processor has a facility which allows the user to search the richTextBox for text.

Currently, my "find" code consists of:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Basic_Word_Processor
{
    public partial class Find : Form
    {
        public Find()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = 0;
            string temp = Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text;
            Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = "";
            Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = temp;
            while (index < Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.LastIndexOf(textBox1.Text))
            {
                Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Find(textBox1.Text, index, Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                index = Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.IndexOf(textBox1.Text, index) +1;
            {
        }
    }
}

        private void Find_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the richTextBox contains the word "TEST", and the user searched for "test", no results would be found.

I asked the same question on the MSDN forum, but I was told to convert the textBox and richTextBox ToLower, which worked, but it made the text in the richTextBox lower case. I do not want it to change the actual text in the richTextBox.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

The textBox is on the Find form and the richTextBox is on the Basic_Word_Processor form.

Comment: Should your comparison always be to `lower case` or do you need it to be case insensitive. i.e. `TeSt` is equal to `tesT`?

Comment: Do You want to find a text in current richtext box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe C# is case sensitive by default, but there is an overload for LastIndexOf (and presumably IndexOf) that allows for a case-insensitive search by specifying parameter such as  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase (or something similar).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224422.aspx.

EDIT:

To clarify, I am proposing changing the code to something like:

```
string findText = textBox1.Text;
string currentText = Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text;
int index = currentText.IndexOf(findText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
while (index >= 0)
{
    Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Find(findText, index, currentText.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
    index = currentText.IndexOf(findText, index+1, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

However, now that I think about it, you should be able to do something simpler such as:

```
int index = Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Find(findText, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
while (index >= 0)
{
    Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
    index = Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Find(findText, index+1, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I have noticed another issue. I was wondering if you could help. If the word I'm searching for is the first word of the line, it doesn't highlight it. So say for example the line is "test 1" and I search for "test", nothing will be highlighted. Why is that?

Comment: It looks like I should have used a `>=` instead of a `>`.  I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use [Regex](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex("text",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            foreach (Match find in reg.Matches(richTextBox1.Text))
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(find.Index, find.Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Calling `text1.Text.ToLower()` will not make the text in your rich text box to be in lower case, because it just returning value.

You can keep it in a string:

`string text = text1.Text.ToLower();`

Then using the string text to process the searching.

Moreover, I don't quite sure about the `Find` method, but it should has a ignore case option. If not, make sure to convert the compared text to lowercase too.

EDIT:

I may be mistaken about which one is the richTextBox, `text1` or `Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1`

If the case is the one in Basic_Word_processor, then in the MSDN link you give in the comment:

```
    string temp = Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.ToLower();
    Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = "";
    Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = temp;
```

It basically said:

- Convert the text in the RichTextBox to lowercase. Keep it in temp
- Set the RichTextBox text ot empty
- Replace the RichTextBox text with the temp

Of course it makes your RichTextBox lowercase.

EDIT2:

Ok seems like the user want to highlight all the found text by given keyword and it is not working. I'll try to answer it.

First, 
Rather than using the Find() method in the rich text box, use the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` instead. I don't see the Find() method to give case insensitive comparison.

Example:

```
string richText = Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.ToLower();
string keyText = textBox1.Text.ToLower();
```

In the while syntax, use the overload string LastIndexOf to compare non-case sensitive. This may not be a matter now as the rich is already in lower state.

```
while (index < richText.LastIndexOf(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Then to find the text, use the following:

```
index = richText.IndexOf(keyText, index);
```

Then set the color like this:

```
Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart = index;
Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionLength = keyText.Length;
Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Comment: this is the link to the MSDN question. I tried following it and it made the text in the richTextBox go to lower case. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualstudiogeneral/thread/7f51c769-ff81-4154-8291-0fd0bf3fff87

Comment: I have updated my answer, however, have you tried your solution yet?

Comment: Why go through the memory overhead of converting the entire contents of the control to lower case, when you can switch the IndexOf and LastIndexOf methods to be case insensitive?  Without testing it, I am assuming that the Find method already is case insensitive (and therefore, is not the problem) since it does not appear to have a case insensitive option.

Comment: How is that achieved? Sorry, I'm new to programming and need stuff explained a bit.

Comment: @Toby I have updated my answer to better explain what I am thinking.

Comment: Cheers, bud. Much appreciated.